# How to integrate "content editable" feature in an HTML form element?

Tags: jquery, forms, html, richtextbox, aloha-editor

I want to use Aloha HTML5 RTE as form element.
http://aloha-editor.org/index.php

Ultimately it boils down to "ContentEditable" attribute.
usually applied as

```
<section contenteditable="true" id="editable">
<h2>Go ahead, edit away!</h2>
<p>Here's a typical paragraph element</p>
<ol>
<li>and now a list</li>
<li>with only</li>
<li>three items</li>
</ol>
</section>
```

I want similar feature for a form element hence I could sent formatted HTML to server side as a form name/value pair.

Is it feasible ? How ?

Comment: can you possibly add a change function to the section, and then populate a hidden input field?  I haven't worked with 'contenteditable' yet, so I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a blog article some time ago on how to use Aloha Editor on textareas: http://www.supnig.com/blog/using-aloha-editor

A WYSIWYG Editor such as the Aloha Editor is much more than contenteditable=true, it accounts for all kinds of strange browser behaviour and adds features to format your content properly.

In case you don't want to use the Aloha Editor you have to listen for the submit event on the form and get the content of a contenteditable element and inject it into the sent data.

Comment: A small demo of your code would be a great help. May be a jsFiddle demo ??

Comment: Above fiddle is quite useful but I observed one interesting aspect which you missed. After pressing submit text-area becomes normal text area with html markup inside it. Aloha Editor simply vanishes. How to keep the aloha editor tied to text area even after submit ??

Could you update the fiddle please ??

Comment: You can just skip the .mahalo() and the Aloha Editor will stay on the textarea. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/znWvT/5/

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks a lot :) Accepting the answer and adding the fiddle in answer !